# Angularjs: access inner array json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am getting JSON objects from .concat in $cookies.
These objects can contain from one to six inner objects. How do I access inner objects? I tried dot notation with no success.

Here are samples of what I am getting and need to parse out to individual sub-objects, so to speak:

Object with one inner object:

```
[{"menuItem.ID":"12","menuItem.Description":"Avocado bacon sandwich","menuItem.Price":5.99}]
```

Object with multiple inner objects:

```
[{"menuItem.ID":"6","menuItem.Description":"Cheese sticks","menuItem.Price":3.99},{"size.ID":1,"size.Description":"Regular","size.Price":0},{"sideOne.ID":2,"sideOne.Description":"Coleslaw $0.99","sideOne.Price":0.99},{"sideTwo.ID":1,"sideTwo.Description":"French Fries","sideTwo.Price":0},{"selectedOption.ID":2,"selectedOption.Description":"Ranch $0.59","selectedOption.Price":0.59}]
```

Comment: What does the parent object look like?  Why doesn't something like `parentObj.innerObjects[0]` work?

Comment: That is an array of objects, also you wont be able to use dot notation with the way you have your object property names, you will have to use bracket notation ie, `somevar[0]["menuItem.Description"]`

Comment: getting "undefined" on somevar[0]["menuItem.Description"] and getting part of the string if somevar[0][0] - getting "[", somevar[0][1] - getting "{". It's like it treats it as string, not an object.

Comment: Update: I changed how the cart is created to make a more uniform object. Here's what I'm getting in console.log for the object: 0: Object
menuItem: Object
menuItem.Description: "Avocado bacon sandwich"
menuItem.ID: "12"
menuItem.Price: 5.99
__proto__: Object
sideOne: Object
sideOne.Description: ""
sideOne.ID: 0
sideOne.Price: 0   but when trying to ng-repeat, nothing is displayed. I tried: <ul ng-repeat="item in cartItem">
<li>{{item[menuItem].ID}} {{item[menuItem].menuItem.ID}}
</li>
<li>item {{item[menuItem]}}</li>
</ul>

Comment: Thank you, Patrick Evans, I ended up using your suggestion, e.g. item["menuItem.Description"] and so forth. It worked.